# Атрибуты конфигурации неподдерживаемые Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security, primefaces

Пытаюсь добавить Spring Security 3 в проект. Вот мой applicationContext.xml

````
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled">
    </global-method-security>

    <security:http auto-config="true" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/views/secondPage.xhtml" access="user"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/registration.xhtml" access="permitAll()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.xhtml" access="permitAll()"/>
        <security:csrf/>
        <security:form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                             username-parameter="username"
                             password-parameter="password" default-target-url="/views/secondPage.xhtml"
                             always-use-default-target="true"/>
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/login.xhtml" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" invalidate-session="true"/>
    </security:http>


    <beans:bean id="http403EntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint">
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="loginBean" class="beans.LoginBean">
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="regBean" class="beans.RegBean">
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="usersBean" class="beans.UsersBean">
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="userDTO" class="entity.UserDTO">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager"
                class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean
                        class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authUserDetailsBean"
                class="security.SecurityUserDetailsService">
        <beans:property name="userDto" ref="userDTO" />
    </beans:bean>


    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="rod" password="koala" authorities="supervisor, teller, user" />
                <user name="dianne" password="emu" authorities="teller, user" />
                <user name="scott" password="wombat" authorities="user" />
                <user name="peter" password="opal" authorities="user" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>```

При запуске выдает такую ошибку

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [user, permitAll()]
````

Answer (score 1):

Заработало. Вместо  secured-annotations="enabled" я поставил use-expressions="true".